# Binding multiple views in one action of backbone router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I create one action in backbone router :

```
 routes: {
    "showCart": "cartList",
 }
 .....
 app_router.on('route:cartList', function (showCart) {
    var cartListView = new CartList();
    cartListView.render();
 });
```

Then I have two or more than than two views to render in that action.

```
var SignInView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $("#rightpanel"),
    initialize:function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render:function(){
        var template = _.template(signinTemplate, {})
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
});
return SignInView;

var CartListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $("#cartlist"),
    initialize:function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        var item = deserializeJSONToObj(window.localStorage.getItem("Cart"));
        var str = '<table>';
        $.each(item, function(i, item) {
            str += '<tr><td><img src="' + item.PictureName + '" alt="Product" width="135px"/></td><td>'+item.Name+'</td></tr>';
        });
        str += '</table>';
        this.$el.html(str);
    }
});
return CartListView;
```

How can I bind these two views in one action in my router?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add changes to router

```
 routes: {
    "showCart": "cartList",
 }
 .....
 app_router.on('route:cartList', function (showCart) {
    var workView = new WorkView();
    workView.render();
 });
```

And create view with name WorkView.

```
var WorkView= Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function(){

    },
    render:function(){
        var signInView = new SignInView ();
        var cartListView = new CartList();
    }
});
```